# Cherry-Picking few commits from another branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have a scenario where I don't want to cherry-pick a specific commit but a range of git commits from remote.
I can do force pull with hard option but that will get all the commits including latest changes from remote.
Please suggest how can I pick range of commits from remote.

---

For instance, this is what I am trying:

```
git checkout -b newbranch 62ecb3

git rebase --onto master 76cada, 56qwqw, 46erer
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use
`git cherry-pick 76cada 56qwqw 46erer`

Comment: To clarify you run this on your local working branch and it will automatically detect the parent commits by their ID(s).

Answer (score 80):

Let's say the history is `A-B-C-D-E-F-G`, and you'd like to cherry-pick `C-D-E-F`.

```
git cherry-pick B..F
```

or

```
git cherry-pick C^..F
```

or

```
git cherry-pick C D E F
```

Comment: The best explanation of cherry pick with few commits!